Artillery run stops upon playwright page error
I have the following config and processor file for my load test with playwright. I have 2 flowfunctions. If there is any error occurred in flowFunction 1 (for example TimeoutError from playwright), artillery run stops immediately.
Is there any way to continue with next flowFunction or with next worker upon page failures?
config:
  processor: "./processor.ts"

  engines:
    playwright:
      {
        launchOptions: { headless: true },
        contextOptions: { ignoreHTTPSErrors: true },
      }

  environments:
    dev:
      target: "mywebsite"
      phases:
        - duration: 5min
          arrivalRate: 1
          maxVusers: 1
          name: "testing"

scenarios:
  - engine: playwright
    name: ABC-Workflow
    flowFunction: "abcWorkflow"
  - engine: playwright
    name: DEF-Workflow
    flowFunction: "defWorkflow"

processor.ts.
import { Page } from 'playwright';
import { BEP, FEP } from '@pages';
import { request } from '@playwright/test';

export async function abcWorkflow(page: Page, vuContext: any, events: any, test: any, next: any): Promise<void> {
  const bepLoginPage = new BEP.LoginPage(page);

  await bepLoginPage.loginAs('User1');
  await bepLoginPage.doAbcStff();
}

export async function defWorkflow(page: Page, vuContext: any, events: any, test: any, next: any): Promise<void> {
  const bepLoginPage = new BEP.LoginPage(page);

  await bepLoginPage.loginAs('User1');
  await bepLoginPage.doDefStff();
}


Your load test is still ongoing. You can gently handle errors within each of your Playwright flow functions, even if they arise in one of them. In this manner, even in the event of an error (such as a TimeoutError), the test will continue. Alternatively, you can catch the error and move on to the next worker or flow function.
modify your abcWorkflow and defWorkflow functions to catch errors:
processor.ts
import { Page } from 'playwright';
import { BEP } from '@pages';

export async function abcWorkflow(page: Page, vuContext: any, events: any, test: any, next: any): Promise<void> {
  const bepLoginPage = new BEP.LoginPage(page);

  try {
    await bepLoginPage.loginAs('User1');
    await bepLoginPage.doAbcStff();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in abcWorkflow:", error);
    events.emit('error', error); // Log error if needed
  } finally {
    next(); 
  }
}

export async function defWorkflow(page: Page, vuContext: any, events: any, test: any, next: any): Promise<void> {
  const bepLoginPage = new BEP.LoginPage(page);

  try {
    await bepLoginPage.loginAs('User1');
    await bepLoginPage.doDefStff();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in defWorkflow:", error);
    events.emit('error', error); // Log error if needed
  } finally {
    next(); 
  }
}

If you want to track failures or success rates, consider updating the events or some state in your context or If you want to implement retries for certain operations within the flow functions, you can add logic to do that before logging an error.
